# How to navigate through inherited widget pages with an app bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi I’m a beginner in flutter and I have an app that have a tab bar view and one of the pages have a bottom notched app bar it have children:-a floating action button and other two material buttons,the floating action button navigates to a page with a form and when the form is filled I want it to navigate to the first material button page and the form has a counter so the form will only stay at the first material button page only until the counter is zero then it will be moved to the second material app button page.And I want this process to loop as long as the user create the form and if there is no created form I want the first material button page to display something like you don’t have anything yet.Please help it would mean a lot